# JQuery stops working without any error message

Tags: javascript, jquery

I noticed on my website that jQuery stops working but I get no error on the console.
I have been trying to test it with very basic code but still the jquery library is loading well, the javascript code works but not the jQuery.
I tested it with Chrome and Internet Explorer on two different computers.
Could someone point me to a direction to look for this problem please ?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"/>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>JQuery</h1>
<p>hide me please</p>

<p id="demo">demo</p>

<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "My First JavaScript";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try getting jquery file on your local system instead of referring from external URL

Comment: Yep, I have tried that too. Same problem.

Comment: You cannot use the "self-closing" syntax (`/>`) to close `<script>` elements. Some browsers will ignore the other scripts in the document when you do that. `<iframe>` works the same way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"/>
```

And let us know if it solved the issue or not. `<script>` tag is not supposed to be self-closed.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"/>
```

this line.
Please remove `/` and close tag in a way `</script>`. Should work.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the jquery script tag should be closed normally. As far as I know script tags are not self closing. I might be wrong though.